# How to assign sample_weights to evaluate function in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

As the size of the sample_weights depends on the size of training data, it makes sense using it with fit function. But when I am using it there I am getting error as

'''

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f3d3806dc520> in <module>()
    272 model_cnn.save(filepath_cnn)
    273 print('>Saved %s' % filepath_cnn)
--> 274 loss_cnn, acc_cnn = model_cnn.evaluate(testX,array(testlabelshuffle), verbose=0)#,sample_weight=None)
    275 print('Test Accuracy CNN: %f' % (acc_cnn*100))
    276 print('Loss CNN: %f' %(loss_cnn))

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

'''

Then I tried passing sample_weights to evaluate function (which I assume is not correct as it evaluates the test data) I again get an error saying sample_weight array is not of the expected size. And this is obvious as the size of sample_weight is equal to training data, not test data.

Please help me in assigning sample weights to training data and solving the above error.

Comment: Which metrics did you specify when you compiled your model?

Comment: I have specified "Accuracy" as the weighted metrics while compiling.